# Вычислить максимальную скорость сообщений в секунду на определенном участке времени

Tags: java, алгоритм

Добрый день. 
Перед мной стоит задача узнать какая максимальная пропускная способность была на определенном участке времени.

Пример использования:
промежуток времени = 1 минута
в этот промежуток времени случилось 600 событий
если посчитать примитивным способом 600/60 = 10 событий/секунду, то не узнаю были ли это 600 сообщений в первую секунду или они случились равномерно в этой минуте.

Так же если подойти более сложным способом вычисления, где сохранять результат каждую секунду а потом сравнивать с максимальным значением то может получится что у нас могут возникнуть такая ситуация:
во вторую половину первой секунды было 300 событий
и в первую половину второй секунды было 300 событий
новый способ зафиксирует что максимальное количество событий было 300
а по факту была секунда в которую произошло 600 событий (половина первой и половина второй секунды).

Может кто знает алгоритм которым можно это все посчитать? или сталкивался с похожей задачей. Буду благодарен любым сведениям, конечно я продолжаю писать свой вариант, но есть надежды что что то подобное уже решалось.

Comment: Кластеризация, видимо...

Comment: А какова миниальная величина дискретизации. Т.е. с какой точностью регистрируется время события

Comment: Mike, время начала события фиксируется с точностью в миллисекундах.Продолжительность и время его завершение отбрасываем.

Comment: Чувствую, что надо установить какие то границы для учета. Ведь скорость можно посчитать зная просто разницу двух соседних событий.  Если между двумя событиями прошла одна миллисекунда, то можно утверждать, что в этот момент скорость составила 1000 в секунду. Это если не учитывать, что в одну миллисекунду может произойти несколько событий. тогда попытка расчета с такой дискретизацией даст, что скорость была бесконечно высока.

Comment: Mike, задача состоит выяснить реальную пропускную способность, а не возможную. Да события идут очень плотно, могут достигать до 1000 в секунду, но они не равномерные, и нужно найти пики на заданном участке времени. Входные данные это время событий в миллисекундах, а результат алгоритма это время начала пики и время окончания, и количество событий на этом участке.

Comment: Это первый вариант решения задачи, где мы храним время всех событий. Есть вторая часть задачи, где мне необходимо выявлять это на ходу, используя минимальное количество памяти, где нет возможности хранить время всех событий.  Суть будет сводиться к тому что мы будем хранить пики для одной минуты, и количество всех событий за эту минуту. Цель решаемой задачи: сократить размер хранящейся информации, выделил те данные которые необходимы, и их группировку.

Comment: Если посмотреть на алгоритмы используемые при резке скорости трафика, там практически везде используется усреднение кол-ва событий за единицу времени. разница только в размере окна. Понятно что одномоментный замер скорости невозможен

Comment: пришел к выводу что все таки лучше по времени. надо считать количества за некую единицу времени. плывущим окном. за эту единицу придется хранить все события (или их точное время в миллисекундах и количество в эту миллисекунду), что бы при движении интервала оценки (ровно N миллисекунд назад) можно было точно оценить эту величину. И дальше уже хранить только эту величину но хранить ее чаще чем сам размер окна, например раз в секунду вычислять за последнюю минуту. И дальше уже искать границы в изменениях этой величины, по абсолютной величине или логарифму, например